# Android studio is showing error during signed build

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am generating the signed build for my project then android studio showing me an error. the error is
`Error:Error: This class should be public(org.linphone.mediastream.video.display.GL2JNIView) [Instantiatable]`. But when I am generating the normal build for the same project studio is not showing any error. Why?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your class **GL2JNIView** public. Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Proguard must be causing the issue.

Add a proguard rule

```
-keep class org.linphone.mediastream.video.display.*
```

Comment: In which file progaurd-android.txt or proguard-rules.pro

Comment: depends on which one you are using. generally it is both by default. If you have not modified the proguard settings in build.gradle put it in .pro

Comment: I can't find proguard-rules.pro file anywhere

Comment: it must be in the `app` folder. If you are using another file just check what file you are using in your app's build.gradle file under buildTypes->Release and add the rule in that file.